# how to get the current year in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fiddle
**http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/100/**

i have dropdown containing years, i need to get the current year in drop down.

```
   <select name="one" class="dropdown-select select1">
    <option value="-1">Select Year</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript

```
var d = new Date(),
year = d.getFullYear();
```

i tried below code but both are not working

```
$('.select1 option:eq('+year +')').prop('selected', true);
```

or

```
$('.select1 option[value="'+year +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/4yfnze7k/ with your second attempt, first one wont work. Have you included jQuery correctly and are you wrapping your code with a DOM-ready-handler?

Comment: The one that uses value works fine. `:eq()` uses the index to select an element (and you don't have one with index 2014). What you maybe want is using `:contains()`

Comment: i am not sure it is working fine now

Comment: @ Spokey thank you even your solution is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
$('.select1 option[value='+year +']').attr('selected',true);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/101/)